# Using iOS 6 autolayout, what would be the proper way to display somthing above an UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios6, modal-dialog, autolayout

In my app, i have a main view controller which sometimes brings a modal view on top of it. This modal view is a UINavigationController with a navigation bar. I want to display an image above the navigation bar, and have the navigation bar appear below the image.

I do not want to subclass anything and the app uses autolayout, i do not want a bunch of delegate callbacks and frame calculations. The view inside the navigation controller (the actual modal content) must still respond to different screen sizes correctly, such as rotation, call status bar etc. Also, no IB solutions please, these views are all managed in code.

How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I would turn off AutoLayout and place the image at the top

Comment: How do i make sure that the view still resizes properly? I do not want a bunch of callbacks and frame calculations. Also, I'm not using Interface Builder. These views are all created programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with your modal view being a navigation controller. I would do it by making that modal controller a UIViewController that you set up as a custom container controller. You can add an image view to the top of this controller's view and add the view of a child view controller (which would be a navigation controller) to the bottom. This would be  a lot easier to do in a storyboard using container views, but it certainly can be done in code.